# Add prefix and suffix to all occurrences of a word in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a text file which I can read as a string for example something like this...

> Hello This is a test string this is a test THIS is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible.

I want the output to append "Foo" to the front and "Bar" to the back of every "this" word (case insensitive) so that the output will look like this:

> Hello FooThisBar is a test string FoothisBar is a test FooTHISBar is just a test ok? Can we solve FooThisBar? Idk, maybe FoothiSBar, is just impossible.

Comment: Can you share your attempt at solving this problem? Then we can help you to fix it.

Comment: Is this just a riddle or do you want to do "serious" language processing? Is search "this" case insenstive and add bar o.k.? Or i.e. must this be a separate word and do not exist within another word etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Regex

#### Match every occurence of `"this"`

Simple [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a [capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#types):

```js
const str = "Hello This is a test string this is a test THIS is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible.";

const result = str.replace(/(this)/gi, "Foo$1Bar")
console.log(result)
```

#### Only match `"this"` when it is a word (works with punctuation)

To avoid matching `"this"` inside a word (e.g, `"abcthisdef"`), you can use a [negative lookahead and negative lookbehind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions):

```js
const str = "Hello This is a test string this is a test THIS is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible.";

const result = str.replace(/(?<!\w)(this)(?!\w)/gi, "Foo$1Bar")
console.log(result)
```

## Non-regex

You can split the string by a space, map through the resulting array and return the modified string only when the item (when converted to lowercase) is equal to `"this"`:

```js
const str = "Hello This is a test string this is a test THIS is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible.";

const result = str.split(" ").map(e => e.toLowerCase() == "this" ? `Foo${e}Bar` : e).join(' ')
console.log(result)
```

The caveat with the above solution is that it will not match `"this"` when it is beside punctuation. E.g, it will not match `"this."`.

To also replace words with *trailing* punctuation, you can first split the string with a regex that matches non-alphanumeric words, check whether the first item is `"this"`, then concatenate the second item after (after first `join`ing, since the second item in the destructure assignment is an array of trailing punctuation characters):

```js
const str = "Hello This is a test string this is a test THIS is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible. this??? this!";

const result = str.split(" ").map(e => {
  let [word, ...punctuation] = e.split(/(?!\w)/g)
  return word.toLowerCase() == "this" ? `Foo${word}Bar${punctuation.join('')}` : e
}).join(' ')
console.log(result)
```

Note that this solution will not work if there is punctuation before the occurence. For example, it will convert `"this"` to `this"`. To avoid this, use the recommended regex solution above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238038/discussion-between-spectric-and-pedram).