# new RegExp doesnt seem to work the same as without

Tags: javascript

A brief explanation:
I have a string which contains sentences. I want to change a specific word to Foo+word+Bar
For example the word that i want to change in this case is "this".
"this" should only be changed when it stands alone for example:

> HellothisOk, HelloThis thisthis and ThisOk

should not be changed, while:

> thiS, "this" this!!! *this* %this!? this? this. THIS

Should change.

The code below works perfect (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69517498/14251221)):

```js
const str = 'Hello This is a test string this is a test THISthis is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible. this??? this! "this "this" this" HellothisOk HelloThis ThisOk';

const result = str.replace(/(?<!\w)(this)(?!\w)/gi, "Foo$1Bar");

console.log(result)
```

But when want to change "this" to a variable like this:

```js
const str = 'Hello This is a test string this is a test THISthis is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible. this??? this! "this "this" this" HellothisOk HelloThis ThisOk';

const variable = "this";

const result = str.replace(new RegExp('(?<!\w)('+variable+')(?!\w)', 'gi'), "Foo$1Bar");

console.log(result);
```

I don't get the same output and I don't understand why.

Comment: Use `\b` to match word boundaries.

Comment: When you use `new RegExp()` you don't put `/` around it. That's just for RegExp literals.

Comment: @Barmar Yup edited that on the post my mistake to put it there, but it still have different output, refresh and check again.

Comment: You also have to escape the backslashes in strings, so `\w` becomes `\\w`

Comment: Using a regex builder tool like https://regexr.com/ has saved my bacon numerous times

Comment: @coll That doesn't help with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to append and prepend `/` when putting a RegExp in a string. Also make sure to escape any backslashes.

```js
const str = 'Hello This is a test string this is a test THISthis is just a test ok? Can we solve This? Idk, maybe thiS, is just impossible. this??? this! "this "this" this" HellothisOk HelloThis ThisOk';

const variable = "this";

const result = str.replace(new RegExp('(?<!\\w)('+variable+')(?!\\w)', 'gi'), "Foo$1Bar");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes I Edited it out it was my mistake but compare it to the output of the first code, it's not the same.

Comment: In first code the " HellothisOk HelloThis ThisOk " is unchanged as it should be while the 2nd code " HelloFoothisBarOk HelloFooThisBar FooThisBarOk " is  the output which is wrong

Comment: i edited my post, does it match now?

Comment: well done forgot about escapes